# How to iterate through all items in list in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, string, str-replace

I'm trying to make a function which will look for items from list in text and if it finds a match, then it should change the found word in the text to "---".

```py
lst = ["str1", "str2", "str3"]

def censor_func_comp(email,lst):
   for words in lst:
      censored_text = email
      if words in censored_text:
         return censored_text.replace(str(words), "---")
   return censored_text
```

I set up, for example, three items in list and the function works correctly, but only for the first item from the list, it doesn't run for other two and I don't understand why.

Please don't give me the whole solution, I need to understand only why the function doesn't work for all items from list.

Comment: Since you did not want to have a complete solution, here is what's wrong: You return the replaced text if only one of the words is found. That's why email is not searched for the subsequent words. With your solution you should replace in email and return email at the end.

Comment: @JürgenBayer Hm... So should the code look like: for words in lst:
    if words in email:
      email.replace(str(words), "---")
    return email ? Unfortunatelly it doens't work at all

Comment: The `if words in censored_text:` statement returns the replaced string and iteration is halted, but it should just continue the loop while replacing the word in the string. Currently if the first item matches criteria, the first replaced result will be returned (just remove the first return statement and `censored_text = email` is irrelevant assignment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already pointed to the error in the code in my comment, but since code does not work well in comments, here is the solution:

```
def censor_func_comp(email, lst):
    censored_text = email
    for words in lst:
        if words in censored_text:
            censored_text = censored_text.replace(str(words), "---")
    return censored_text
```

The point is that the function must not return already if only one of the searched words is found and replaced, but search and replace the others as well.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I understand what was the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Your code has two problems. First, you are returning the string on each iteration, it only replaces the first one and will return the result. Second, replace does not make any changes to the object, it returns a new one. So you should remove the in-loop return, and also replace the censored_text with the new on each iteration.

```
censored_text = censored_text.replace(str(word), "---")
```

By the way, please type your code in the editor, it will help others to test and edit your code.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming `email` and `lst` are both lists. So you are iterating over `lst` and checking if `words` exist in `email`. So what `in` operator does with list is it looks for the exact same item in list. In your case it will try to find `words` in `email` exactly as a list item. So here's my solution to your problem and i am hoping that's what you are looking for and i am not posting code:

1. Convert your email list into a string separated by `' '`.
2. Iterate over `lst` and replace in string if `words in string`.
3. After the end of the loop return the string by splitting it with `' '` so it can be a list again.

If `email` is a string then just replace `return censored_text.replace(str(words), "---")` with `email = censored_text.replace(str(words), "---")`